# Symfony's Request and reverse proxy

Tags: symfony, reverse-proxy

I've apache2 and nginx. I set "trust proxy headers" to true in configuration, but anyway get internal ip when calls `$request->getClientIp();` What do I wrong?

If I calling `getClientIp` with parameter `$proxy = true` then I getting correct IP. But there is configuration where proxy headers enabled, aren't that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is an issue, fixed by this merge https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/40599ec0a24e688ef5903e2bd3cfb29b5ab29a18

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** you always need to use `$proxy = true` if you're planning on using some kind of reverse proxy. With this parameter set (and `trustProxyData();` enabled), `$this->getClientIp();` will return the correct IP with reverse proxy.

**Explanation:** even after configured, proxy headers will return `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` or `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` as the user IP, while `REMOTE_ADDR` will return server localhost address (most likely 127.0.0.1). `$proxy = true` checks exactly that. Here's the source code for this function:

```
public function getClientIp($proxy = false)
{
    if ($proxy) {
        if ($this->server->has('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
            return $this->server->get('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        } elseif (self::$trustProxy && $this->server->has('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
            return $this->server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        }
    }

    return $this->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
}
```

Comment: I was seen this code. But there is proxy in production and no proxy on dev test server. Sho what I should write? `getClientIp(IS_PROXY_ENABLED)`? This is ugly. `trustProxyData()` called when I enable proxy in Symfony's config.

Comment: why bother? when there is no proxy, both headers `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will be unset and `REMOTE_ADDR` is returned.